# Update DOM when Angular 2 component property changes

Tags: angular

Just recently moved from Angular 1 to Angular 4, and having a bit of a tough time understanding why the DOM isn't updating when a component property is updated. I've searched and read countless posts, and can't find anything that seems to answer this.

I have an app that has a component for displaying error messages, called MessageComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';                                                                   

 @Component({                                                                                                               
   selector: 'message',                                                                                                     
   templateUrl: './message.component.html',                                                                                 
   styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']                                                                                   
 })                                                                                                                         

export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {                                                                          

  messages: Array<string>;                                                                                                 

  constructor() {                                                                                                          

  }                                                                                                                        

  ngOnInit() {                                                                                                             
    this.messages = ['My messages'];                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                        

  /* Takes an array of messages */                                                                                         

  showErrors(errors) {                                                                                                     
    this.messages = errors;                                                                                                
  }
}
```

The template is straightforward:

```
<div class="message">                                                                                                      
  <p>Messages go here</p>                                                                                                  
  <div class="error">                                                                                                      
     <ul>                                                                                                                 
       <li *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</li>                                                              
     </ul>                                                                                                                
  </div>                                                                                                                   
</div>
```

And I'm calling the `showErrors` method from another component:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';                                                                         

  import { MessageComponent } from  '../message/message.component';                                                          

  @Component({                                                                                                               
    selector: 'app-signup',                                                                                                  
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',                                                                                  
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']                                                                                    
  })                                                                                                                         
  export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {                                                                           

    email: string;                                                                                                           
    password: string;                                                                                                        
    cardNumber: string;                                                                                                      
    expiryMonth: string;                                                                                                     
    expiryYear: string;                                                                                                      
    cvc: string;                                                                                                             
    plan: string;                                                                                                            

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private auth: Auth, private message: MessageComponent) { }           

    signupUser() {                                                                                                           
      // do stuff here, then call back with status                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }, (status: number, response: any) => {                                                                                
        if (status == 200) {                                                                                                 
          // yay, do success stuff                                                                                                
        } else {                                                                                                             
          console.log('Error', response.error.message);                                                                      
          this.message.showErrors([response.error.message]);                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                    
      });                                                                                                                    
    }
```

The `signupUser()` method is called from this form, which is `signup.component.html`, the template for the SignupComponent:

```
<message></message>                                                                                                      
<h1>Signup</h1>                                                                                                          
<form (submit)="signupUser()">                                                                                           
  <div class="row">                                                                                                      
    <div class="small-12 columns">                                                                                       
      <label>Email address                                                                                               
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email">                                                           
      </label>                                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                                               
  </div>                                                                                                                 
  <div class="row">                                                                                                      
    <div class="small-12 columns">                                                                                       
      <label>Password                                                                                                    
        <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password">                                                   
      </label>                                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                                               
  </div>                                                                                                                 
  <div class="row">                                                                                                      
    <div class="small-12 columns">                                                                                       
      <label>Card Number                                                                                                 
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cardNumber" name="card-number" data-stripe="number">                           
      </label>                                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                                               
  </div>                                                                                                                 
  <div class="row">                                                                                                      
    <div class="small-6 columns">                                                                                        
      <label>Expiration Date (MM/YY)                                                                                     
        <span><input type="text" size="2" [(ngModel)]="expiryMonth" name="expiry-month" placeholder="MM"><input type="text" size="2" [(ngModel)]="expiryYear" name="expiry-year" placeholder="YY"></span>                                                      
      </label>                                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                                               
    <div class="small-6 columns">                                                                                        
      <label>CVC                                                                                                        
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cvc" name="cvc">                                                                
      </label>                                                                                                          
    </div>                                                                                                              
  </div>                                                                                                                
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">                                                                                 
</form>
```

Hopefully that's enough to get the gist. What I'm able to observe is that `this.messages` inside the `MessagesComponent` DOES indeed change to the correct value when called, however, the DOM doesn't update.

What am I missing here? I feel like I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how Angular detects the changes to the component property and propagates that to the DOM, but I have no clue what it is I'm missing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It normally is. We would need to know where the call that updates the model originates from. Search for invoking change detection manually

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer - the call that updates the model is invoked in the SignupComponent, right near the end: `this.message.showErrors(...)`. Is that what you're asking about?

Also, I tried injecting `ApplicationRef` and calling `ref.tick()`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference (in terms of trying to invoke change detection manually).

Comment: Yes, but where is `signupUser` being called from? `NgZone.run` or ’ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` will fix it, but it would be better if the root cause could be fixed

Comment: Ah, gotcha @GünterZöchbauer - I just added that code to the post. In short, `signupUser()` is called from `signup.component.html`, the template for `SignupComponent`.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: I see you define MessageComponent as a component and then you pass it to the SignupComponent using Dependency Injection (i.e. MessageComponent is passed in the constructur of SignupComponent). At the same time you have the MessageComponent referenced in the template of the SignupComponent (first line). What I would do is to define "messages' as an Input property in MessageComponent and then fill such property  from within SignupComponent any time an error occurs

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue today and I resolved like this way:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

... it is going to notify changes every one second

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){

     setInterval(() => {
       this.ref.detectChanges()
     }, 1000);

 }
```

... if you whant just notify ones, you need to use this line after u need it

```
 this.ref.detectChanges()
```

Comment: That does not really solve the issue. Angular should trigger change detection automatically when there's a change on any Input property. The question here is: Why is it not happening? Maybe you changed the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` on some affected component?

Comment: It was happening with a ng2 smart table  i solved with different solution, i know it isnt a good solution even i will remove it

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange the code as follows. The whole idea is that MessageComponent has an Input property, to be used to receive the messages it has to show, and that SignupComponent passes the error messages to the MessageComponent using template binding sintax.

**MessageComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';                                                                   

 @Component({                                                                                                               
   selector: 'message',                                                                                                     
   templateUrl: './message.component.html',                                                                                 
   styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']                                                                                   
 })                                                                                                                         

export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {                                                                          

  @Input() messages: Array<string>; // Input property                                                                                                

  constructor() {                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                        

  ngOnInit() {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }  
}
```

**SignupComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';                                                                         

  @Component({                                                                                                               
    selector: 'app-signup',                                                                                                  
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',                                                                                  
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']                                                                                    
  })                                                                                                                         
  export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {                                                                           

    email: string;                                                                                                           
    password: string;                                                                                                        
    cardNumber: string;                                                                                                      
    expiryMonth: string;                                                                                                     
    expiryYear: string;                                                                                                      
    cvc: string;                                                                                                             
    plan: string; 

    messages: Array<string>;  // property used to pass the messages to the MessageComponent                                                                                                         

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private auth: Auth) { }           

    signupUser() {                                                                                                           
      // do stuff here, then call back with status                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }, (status: number, response: any) => {                                                                                
        if (status == 200) {                                                                                                 
          // yay, do success stuff                                                                                                
        } else {                                                                                                             
          console.log('Error', response.error.message);                                                                      
          this.messages = [response.error.message];                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                    
      });                                                                                                                    
    }
```

**SignupComponent template**

```
<!-- TEMPLATE BINDING -->
<message [messages]="messages"></message>                                                                                                      
<h1>Signup</h1>                                                                                                          
<form (submit)="signupUser()">   
..... the rest of your code
</form>
```

Comment: This makes total sense to me, but doesn't seem to update the DOM either.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to see what kind of object you receive in `response.error.message`. The code assumes that you receive an array of strings. If you receive a simple string (and not an Array of strings) you would probably not see anything.

Comment: turns out, this DOES work if I wrap it in ngzone.run(). Apparently, this seems like an issue with the async nature of the call (I'm using the Stripe API in this call, and response.error.message is the return value from that call). When I wrapped it in that, your solution works perfectly. I'd still like to encapsulate that a bit better to make it easier to implement elsewhere, but it's certainly a workable solution!